# Javascript/Jquery beginner question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning some jQuery basics with this great book: http://jqfundamentals.com/book/

There is an example that doesn't return the right result.

Here is the code:

```
  var myName = 'the global object',

      sayHello = function () {
          console.log('Hi! My name is ' + this.myName);
      },

      myObject = {
          myName : 'Rebecca'
      };

  var myObjectHello = sayHello.bind(myObject);

  sayHello();       // logs 'Hi! My name is the global object'
  myObjectHello();  // logs 'Hi! My name is Rebecca'
```

The log returns `undefined` instead of `the global object` for `sayHello();` and I'd like to know why...

Comment: Either this is an implementation issue ('cause this works fine in Chrome)

Comment: @cwallenpoole . . . either it's an implementation issue, or what?

Comment: @Levi apparently the "or" is "or I have ADD"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work properly, unless you've wrapped that code in another function, creating a new variable scope.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RKYNn/

As such, `myName` would not be available as a property on the global object.

So if you did this:

```
(function() {

  var myName = 'the global object',

      sayHello = function () {
          console.log('Hi! My name is ' + this.myName);
      },

      myObject = {
          myName : 'Rebecca'
      };

  var myObjectHello = sayHello.bind(myObject);

  sayHello();       // logs 'Hi! My name is the global object'
  myObjectHello();  // logs 'Hi! My name is Rebecca'

})();
```

...you'd get `undefined` because `myName` is no longer global, and `this` in the function is a reference to the global object.

Comment: @patrick dw: my guess is that it was dave, we both got downvoted simultaneously :P

Comment: Agreed, this answer is correct. I suspect the OP had his code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @Andrew Funny, that's exactly what I suggested in my post. +1

Comment: Ok, I get it! Thanks. @Andrew Whitaker you're right about the code wrapped in `$(document).ready()`. It makes sense to me now

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are running `onDomReady` or `onLoad`. If I am correct, that is your problem (or appears to be when playing around in jsFiddle).  Don't wrap it up and load it in the head or body after your jQuery.

See http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/euprL/

The reason has to do with scoping.  [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) sums it up quite well, I think.

Answer (score 2):

`The global object` isn't what it's actually going to say. It was implied that it will return the global `window` object, which is where global variables and such live. Unless you have a global variable named `myName` the value will be `undefined`.

**Edit**
First time through I missed the `var myName = 'the global object';`. That `var` makes it it part of the scope it's currently in, so as others have pointed out, unless you're in the global scope, it won't find the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Tested your code like this and it works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myName = 'the global object',

      sayHello = function () {
          console.log('Hi! My name is ' + this.myName);
      },

      myObject = {
          myName : 'Rebecca'
      };

  var myObjectHello = sayHello.bind(myObject);

  sayHello();       // logs 'Hi! My name is the global object'
  myObjectHello();  // logs 'Hi! My name is Rebecca'

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Can you give us some details on the context of this script?

Comment: Yes, context was the key. I wrapped the code in `$(document).ready()`